# yum + dependencies not logical when installing openjdk

Tags: rhel, software-installation, yum, rpm, java

we are tryng to install the `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64.rpm`

```
yum localinstall java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is registered to Red Hat Subscription Management, but is not receiving updates. You can use subscription-manager to assign subscriptions.
Examining java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64.rpm: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64
Marking java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 1:1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java-1.8.0-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7 for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64 (/java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: java-1.8.0-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7
           Installed: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64 (installed)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64 (local)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

we can see from the output that:

```
 Requires: java-1.8.0-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7
```

but what I not understand is that we try to install the same rpm that is required!!

```
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

so what is  going here?

current installed rpm's

```
rpm -qa | grep openjdk
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64

 java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b10, mixed mode)
```

the only way to install it is by rpm ( not by yum )

```
rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.171-2.6.13.2.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel` and `java-1.8.0-openjdk` versions need to match exactly.

in short:

```
yum downgrade java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

I just wrote a whole answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498755/installing-python36-devel-on-rhel7-failing/57519956#57519956

Comment: but we not found devel as java version

Comment: we cant downgrade because the min java we need is 1.8.0_171

Comment: what bad with my option - "rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.171-2.6.13.2.el7.x86_64.rpm"

Comment: But “rpm -V” just verified installed packages, it doesn’t install anything. The problem you have is that the different releases of the packages cause yum to fail during the dependency check.   Every package must match.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fix it with ***yumdownloader***:

```
# Install yumdownloader
yum install yum-utils

# Download the missing packages
yumdownloader java-1.8.0-openjdk --resolve --destdir pkgs

# Install all at once
yum install pkgs/*.rpm
```